# XTK won't load converted VTK STRUCTURED POINTS into a NRRD file

Tags: vtk, xtk

I'm using teem library to convert an ASCII .vtk file with float STRUCTURED POINTS to nrrd. The file at ouput seems to be a raw NRRD0001 and I've been able to load it correctly in paraview, so it seems to be ok. **When I load that file in XTK I have no error messages but nothing displayed.**

I've also tried to convert it via unu to have gzipped encoding with no success:

```
teem-unu save -f "nrrd" -e "gzip" -i "./inputfile.vtk" -o "./outputfile.nrrd"
```

I noted that XTK working nrrd files is of type NRRD0004.

May I have to save it with this formatting? How can I save it in teem as 0004?

Thanks in advance,

Andrea

---

**This is my convert simple procedure:**

```
#include <teem/nrrd.h>

Nrrd *nrrd = nrrdNew();
if (nrrdLoad(nrrd, argv[1], NULL)==0 && nrrdSave(argv[2], nrrd, NULL)==0)
       printf("success\n");
```

---

**VTK file HEADER:**

```
# vtk DataFile Version 2.0
Image Builder vtk output
ASCII
DATASET STRUCTURED_POINTS
DIMENSIONS 30 20 20
SPACING 10.266666 8.000000 11.900000
ORIGIN -154.000000 -176.470001 -119.000000
POINT_DATA 12000
SCALARS volume_scalars float 1
LOOKUP_TABLE default
```

---

**converted NRRD file output:**

```
NRRD0001
# Complete NRRD file format specification at:
# http://teem.sourceforge.net/nrrd/format.html
content: Image Builder vtk output
type: float
dimension: 3
sizes: 30 20 20
spacings: 10.266666 8 11.9
axis mins: -154 -176.470001 -119
endian: little
encoding: raw
```

---

**visualizing script is the same as http://lessons.goxtk.com/11/**

```
var r = new X.renderer('r');
    r.init();

    volume = new X.volume();
    volume.load('pocas.nrrd');             
    r.add(volume);        
    r.camera().setPosition(120,80,160);
    r.render();
```

Answer (score 0):

this is probably not supported yet (the .vtk file).

can you provide a screenshot of what you want to accomplish so we get an idea of what you want to do..

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when i tried to convert dicom files to nrrd files. I notice that the help in the unu make command is more detailed that the unu make webpage help. In my case  i used the follow unu command:

```
./unu make -i CT/patient_%03d.dcm 1 369 1 -e raw -bs -1 -en little -t short 
-s 369 369 369 -dirs "(0.4,0,0) (0,0.4,0) (0,0,0.4)" -spc LPS -o CT.nrrd
```

In this case the key to generate a nrrd file as 0004 is the use of -dirs and -spc options. i hope that this help you!

from the unu make help:

```
-dirs <v0 v1 ...> , --directions <v0 v1 ...> = (NOTE: must quote whole
                 vector list) The "space directions": the vectors in space
                 spanned by incrementing (by one) each axis index (the
                 column vectors of the index-to-world matrix transform),
                 OR, "none" for non-spatial axes. Give one vector per
                 axis. (Quoting around whole vector list, not
                 individually, is needed because of limitations in the
                 parser) (string)

  -spc <space> , --space <space> = identify the space (e.g. "RAS", "LPS")
                 in which the array conceptually lives, from the nrrdSpace
                 airEnum, which in turn determines the dimension of the
                 space. Or, use an integer to give the dimension of a
                 space that nrrdSpace doesn't know about By default (not
                 using this option), the enclosing space is set as
                 unknown. (string)
```

Regards,

P

Comment: Many Thanks Mr. P

I've done by saving in header + data and after making new header:

 teem-unu save -f "nrrd" -e "ascii" -i infile.vtk -o "./h0001.nhdr" -od "datafile.nrrd"

and then:

  teem-unu make -i ./datafile.nrrd -e "ascii" -en little -t float -s 102 53 80 -dirs "(3.01,0,0) (0,3.03,0) (0,0,02.97)" -spc LPS -o "./outfile.nrrd"

Answer (score 0):

Just found this via google.  I wrote unu and nrrd.  If XTK can't usefully load the file its a property of how XTK handles the nrrd format, not your file.

Just thought I'd point out that for unu, you don't have to quote every single string- just those strings which contain spaces.

```
 unu save -f nrrd -e gzip -i ./inputfile.vtk -o ./outputfile.nrrd
```

will work just as well.